# How to validate a Binary Tree?

Tags: tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search, b-tree

I have been doing some digging around Binary Tree and Binary Source Tree. Ran into this very fundamental question of the Tree (BT) and challenges the properties of a Binary Tree to be proven.

---

Question:  Given a node (the root), check if this is a valid Binary Tree. Not asking to validate if given BT is a BST, but simply asking to check if below is a BT.

```
Valid:
  X1
 /  \
X4   X5
 \    \
  X3   X7

Invalid:
  X1
 /  \
X4   X5
 \  /  \
  X3   X7


# A Python class that represents an individual node in a BT
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.val = key 

    def isNotBinaryTree(root):
        # code here

if isNotBinaryTree(root):
   print "True"
else: 
   print "False"
```

I do know this is NOT a binary tree (in fact, this is **not even** a tree by its definition and properties).
Thing is... how do I prove or validate this? Or how do I validate this is not a BT where x4 and x5 -> x3 (multiple parent (nodes) point to a same child node? ***No data provided! What would the algorithm/logic look like if I were to solve this? (Python x.x preferred)

Comment: Do a dfs and check if it contains a cycle.

Comment: @DhruvSehgal  I'm guessing "dfs" refers to "Depth-first Strategy" here? And when you say "contains a cycle" for example, check to see if these nodes (X4, X3, X1, X5) form a cycle?

Comment: Yes, That's exactly what I am saying

Comment: That was my initial thought ... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your data structure, it should be pretty easy to take a node and recursively see if there's a cycle with a simple function like:

```
def hasCycle(node, seen = set()):
    if node in seen: return True
    seen.add(node)
    if node.left and hasCycle(node.left, seen): 
        return True
    if node.right and hasCycle(node.right, seen): 
        return True
    return False
```

This just does a depth first search and keeps a set of nodes visited. If you see a node twice, that's a cycle.

Comment: Newbie here... do you mind explaining the code esp. on the part where 
 `"seen = set()" `

Comment: @JohnDoe the `seen = set()` is a default argument in python. If nothing is passed to the function's second argument it will make `seen` a new `set`. It saves the trouble of making a set outside the scope of the function. On each recursion we pass the `seen` set back in as an argument allowing a single set to be used for all the recursions. You can also do this same thing with a while loop and stack instead of recursion.

Comment: Ahhh that make sense. That way you keep track of what you see in the set.

Comment: What if a cycle is not present but a node has three child instead? That would not be a valid binary tree too.

Answer (score 0):

Followed the link below to get more in-depth description on BT/BST: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

```
def nodes_visited(root, key):
    if root.next:
        if root.next in key: 
            return True
        key.append(root)
        return nodes_visited(root.next, key)
    return False

def has_cycle(head):
    return nodes_visited(root=head, key=[])
```